# Meteor Mongodb first object array not selectable with dot notation

Tags: mongodb

I have tried and tried on Meteor and on Robomongo (Mongodb) to select objects with dot notation.

I would like to be able to filter team.0.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread objects (sometimes subjects can be fields or arrays - thats another issue)
In the first image I can select  team.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread and get back all the subOjects of team (team has siblings not shown in images)
[image: team.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread]

The second image I tried team.0.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread and I get no fields.

[image: team.0.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread]

Lastly i tried team.[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread and 
team[0].wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread and get the same result : 0 fields

I am at a loss and would like some help. Thank you

[image: team0.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do now? Because in your first command, you already have a list of team that match your criteria and then, put it into the loop of `meteor` to process. Why do you need to find only the first one ? By the way, in order to select the nth of the result set in `mongodb`, you will need something like `skip` and `limit`

```
db.collections.find({'team.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread':1}).limit(1).skip(0)
```

(in skip, you need to pass the offset you need to reach to)

Also, if you only care about the first one, `findOne` is the one you need to do the query

```
db.collections.findOne({'team.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread':1})
```

Be aware that the syntax of `mongodb` and `meteor` for querying is a bit different

Comment: Team is an array with different values for in [0] and [1] in subobjects even though the keys are the same

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I have tried it now in Robomongo. First query did not fetch any results and second query resulted in null. Both did not work in Meteor as well.

Comment: it is only the combination of limit, skip and exists.  if the find solely can return some results, then the skip, limit will only filter on the result set. what does mongo give if you use your first command in the question with.limit(1)

Comment: Fetched 0 record(s) in 2ms

Comment: The first query with limit just limits to one document and the skip just skips documents. None help to filter the team.0. array and subdocuments that I am looking for.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why .find({}, {'team.0.wageringStats.wageringStraightSpread':1}) or similar does not work.